# Any issues with keeping Mail folder on the cloud in macOS?

Tags: email, dropbox, apple-mail, cloud-storage, macos-highsierra

The situation is that I am about to add an iMac to my current Macbook Air. iMac will stay at home as my main machine, and the Macbook Air will be used when traveling. I am using Apple Mail for all my emails, with plenty of mail stored on my Local Folders on the disk (beyond the 3 IMAP accounts).

Now, I needed to find a way to keep all the stored mail in-sync between the 2 computers. Eventually got through to a knowledgeable Apple Tech Level 2 person, and we worked out a solution that seems to work so far:

1. I moved the whole Mail folder from ~username/Library to Dropbox.
2. Created a symlink to it "ln -s ~/Dropbox/Mail ~/Library/Mail"

Any possible issues I might need to be mindful of with such a configuration?